# Custom Looping of Wordpress Posts

Tags: loop, count

I have been working on a Wordpress theme from few days. 
I want to achieve modern like layout in my theme's frontpage.

But I am having no clue that how to achieve it.

Now my wordpress theme loops the post in this manner

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
<article class="post1"></article>
<article class="post2"></article>
<article class="post3"></article>
<article class="post4"></article>
<article class="post5"></article>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve in the above code is

```
<div class="col-xs-8">

   <!-- First post Wrapper-->
   <div class="first-post">
      <article class="post1"></article>
   </div>

<!-- Rest all post Wrapper-->
   <div class="all-posts">
      <article class="post2"></article>
      <article class="post3"></article>
      <article class="post4"></article>
      <article class="post5"></article>
   </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a possible solution with this custom looping for a frontpage.

Comment: Please don't ask for urgent help - we all donate our time here, as and when we can.

Comment: Instead of needing *urgent help*, rather file an [edit] and explain to us what you have tried **yourself** and add your code and explain where you are failing. *I need urgent help* and showing us no effort is not going to get you any help at all. ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry for using wrong word friends.

Actually it's been three days I have been trying to achieve the result I mentioned above.

So you can imagine what was in my head and in that tension I asked for urgent help.

Hope you may understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I believe this should work

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <?php $count  = 1; ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php if $count = 1; ?>
            <!-- First post Wrapper-->
            <div class="first-post">
              <article class="post1"></article>
            </div>

            <!-- Rest all post Wrapper-->
            <div class="all-posts">
        <?php else : ?>
                <article class="post<?php echo $count; ?>"></article>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $count++; endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi RiaanZA

Thanks for your time, but it's not working with the post loop.
I have tried the similar code earlier before posting this question, it didn't work with

Comment: It's not working for sticky posts?
Do you know any solution so that it should work for sticky posts too??

Comment: A lot of Thanksssssss to you RiaanZA

You saved my day